# Text capitalization (maybe Phraseexpress)

Tags: phraseexpress

I need a quick and convenient way to capitalize the text that I've selected, independent of the environment (I know how to do it in Microsoft Word, but I need to do it anywhere).

I have Phraseexpress and I know it can do that for me, but my code isn't working

```
{#uppercase {#insert $clip}}
```

Either a working code or another tool would be just fine.

Please advise! Thank you!

Comment: Please expand on what you mean by "independent of the environment". Do you mean you need this function on ALL possible computers? A subset of possible computers? Please use the edit button to add this and other necessary information to the question. Note: SuperUser is NOT a software recommendation or code/script writing service. You have given us some code already and a program, but you have also asked us to write you code and suggest applications. The first part is OK and certainly something we can help with, the latter parts are NOT ok and should be remove from the question.

Comment: Please add what about this code isn't work, any output in the console, or any other data and evidence regarding the nature of the failure of the code you have tried. Simply saying it doesn't work is insufficient. Finally, please explain what sort of capitalization you're trying to do: first letter of sentences, some words, all letters of all words, something else?

Comment: Regardless of the environment = no matter if one is using Microsoft Word, a browser, Notepad, Explorer... Skype... just anywhere.
Doesn't work = doesn't do anything. Nothing happens.
Capitalization = ALL CAPS LIKE THIS.

Comment: Edits should be made to the original post, not added in comments. This allows the original post to improve and adjust until it is complete and sufficient to provide all necessary information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Download PhraseExpress from http://download.phraseexpress.com
2. Create a phrase with this macro:

   `{#clipboard -copy}{#uppercase {#trim {#insertclipboard}}}`
3. Assign a hotkey to that phrase.

Then, in any application, highlight the text, you wish to uppercase and press the assigned hotkey. Voila.

Comment: Sir, you are 100% awesome! Thank you, sincerely! Thank you!

Comment: What programming language is that, by the way? Something common or is it PE specific?

Comment: PhraseExpress specific but we changed to a visual "programming" approach in alter versions.